# find files that have specific word in a loop?

Tags: python

In that folder there are files called: `a11.shp,a11.shx,u21.shp,u21.shx`

```
import os 
words = ('a11','u21')
for root, dirs,files in os.walk(r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\folder1'):
    for i in files: 
        if i in words:
            print(i)
```

> TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str

It requires some kind of an index for the tuple to run for all the items.

I want to use it as 'contains' that word and it doesn't work like contains the `in` in this case.

How can this be done when giving these exact words in the tuple. Without `startswith`.

Comment: do you want to match the exact words, or just partial words? For instance can `a11_xxxx.txt` matches `a11` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the (working) idea of `if words in i:` would be `if any(w in i for w in words)`, but that matches substrings (not exact strings) and is not very fast.

You have to do this the other way round. Test `file_without_extension in words`.

For instance like this:

```
for i in files: 
    # check if the filename (without extension) is in "words" iterable
    if os.path.splitext(i)[0] in words:
        print(i)
```

and if you have a lot of "words" make that a `set` instead of a `tuple` for faster lookup (`words = {'a11','u21'}`).

Comment: Can you write an example of what you describe?

Comment: I'm more inclined to agree with `if any(w in i for w in words)` since `filename in words` would require a full match.  It may be that OP is only looking for partial match (although the example shows a full one).  Also might explain why they shy away from `startswith`.

Comment: OP requests: "How can this be done when giving these exact words in the tuple. Without startswith" I may have understood it wrong.

Comment: yes, that's what I thought using any. Nice, but I wrote it wrong. Or this `os.path.basename(i).split('.')[0] in words`.

Comment: Actually the guy that answered got it right. The reason I didn't choose `startswith` is just to learn about alternative ways that don't require full match.

Answer (score 0):

I find that choosing descriptive names for variables makes the code easier to read. Examine my example below:

```
import os

words = ('a11','u21')

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\folder1'):
    for filename in files:
        for word in words:
            if word in filename:
                print('Match: "', word, '" is in "', file, '"', sep='')
```

This code produces the result I think you are aiming for.